# Is Vidar alive at the end of the series, or else, how did he die?

Tags: ragnarok

In the final episode of the series [Ragnarok](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9251798), it is insinuated that all supernatural elements in the course of the series

> happened entirely in Magne's imagination.

Now, while we can ascribe the other disappearances that were implied to be murders directly resulting from the supernatural happenings (most notably, the elderly couple and Fjor's new secretary) to the fact that Magne simply didn't see those people again and thus

> imagined some gruesome ending of theirs, even though they are still alive

the case is quite a bit different with Vidar. Once he was deceased, throughout the series, his death was presented as a direct result of the supernatural struggle with Magne.

> If this supernatural struggle didn't really happen, though,

did Vidar die by different causes when his death was shown in the series? Or is he actually still alive in the final episode?

Comment: There is absolutely no way to know what the writers intended to be taken as correct from the previous seasons, since even supernatural (or even mundane?) events for which Magnus was not present are (apparently?) meant to have been taken as not having happened. About all that one can say from the perspective of the last episode is that people resembling the characters in the rest of the series apparently exist, Magnus apparently knew them, and Isolde apparently still died, although how is completely up in the air. But maybe is a ghost.

Comment: Honestly, I don't get the impression that they had the idea for the final episode in mind when they made the first episode of the last season, to say nothing of the first one, so trying to reconcile it with the rest is going to be quite an effort.

Comment: @Adamant: Well, there is still a slight chance this is cleared up and I missed it: E.g. if during the graduation celebration, we could glimpse Vidar happy and alive among the audience, that would be sufficient to show he's actually still alive. Or alternatively, a glimpse during the same scene of an image of his, with a caption like "We miss you." would imply he's indeed dead (even though we wouldn't know how).